# Float icon to the left and not add to text padding via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a Bootstrap based app with a table that has 'indented' text in the first column.  I would like to add an icon (Fontawsome) to the space in the indent.  The icon is dynamic as its only displayed if there is a 'note' for that row.  Here is what I want:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

Here is my example code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jasper502/ju8we9b6/11/

I have tried different float, display options and can't seem to figure this out.  I am sure it's easy - my CSS skills are pretty basic.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.indent {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="indent">Row 1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
        <span class="indent">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="indent">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated as per comment:**

You could then use absolute position on your icon container. This would not affect the position of its siblings irrespective of the icon's presence or absence.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.indent {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.dummyIcon{
  position: absolute;
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="indent">Row 1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="dummyIcon"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
        <span class="indent">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="indent">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you right align your second span containing the row name, it would work fine.
The bs4 class that I have used is `float-right`.
Also you would need to fix a width for your td, so if the icon disappears, your column width remains same.

**Working snippet below:**

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.indent {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="indent float-right">Row 1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
        <span class="indent float-right">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="indent float-right">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's close except when the column cell is wide the text pulls to the right - the intent is the text is indented by a fixed amount regardless of the icon presence.

Comment: I have updated the code to apply absolute positioning on the span containing the icon. This way, it would affect its siblings and no changes need to be done anywhere except on the span itself.

Comment: That's perfect - I always forget about some of these like position.  I often just fiddle in the Chrome inspector until I stumble across the right CSS and it looks the way I want lol 

Comment: Hahaha... no worries. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a table instead of flex or so. Why not add the icon in a cell to the left - it will collapse if there is no icon OR you can make the cell width constant like your padding is now

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


tr {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align:right
}

tr th {text-align:center}

td {  padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I may try that - my actual table is large with colspan rows etc.  I worry that the headers etc will not align with an inconsistant number of `td` in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the comment icon in every row - hidden by default - and make it appear only when it has the class `visible` using the following code:

```
.fa-comment:not(.visible) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And this is what it will look like:

[image]

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.indent {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.fa-comment:not(.visible) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i></span>
        <span class="indent">Row 1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment visible"></i></span>
        <span class="indent">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i></span>
        <span class="indent">Row 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's an option also - lots of choices here.  Was thinking there has to be a simple CSS option that makes this work.